# How can I play triplets along with quavers?

Tags: piano

I have these measures that I want to play, I can play the left and right hands separately with a metronomme at crotchet=75. My usual method is to play each parts slowly starting at 30 and increasing tempo by 5 after I am successfully able to play that part with that hand. Finally I play both hands starting at 30 and similarly proceeding. I am having hard time independently playing triplets and quavers.

I am having problem mainly at the last crotchet beats of 34th, 36th and 38th bar.

To be honest, I haven't played that much triplets and even playing them individually is quite difficult for me. I haven't played a complete song that had triplets in it.

[image]

Comment: The question linked above will explain triplets against quavers, but I suggest you'll have an easier time of it if you learn to execute triplets confidently on their own first.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate but I have a very simple way of breaking this down. Subdivide the beat into the lowest common denominator, 6. Eighth notes are 1 and 4 and triplets are 1,3 and 5.   The second 8th note falls squarely between the second and third triplets, super simple! Think of the carol of the bells motif, the 1st and 3rd notes are the eighths and the first second and fourth notes are the triplets.